# Binding multiple divs (classes) to dynamic values in Angular

Tags: angular

Inside td I want to use step progress bar which dynamically changes according to the value fetched. I am able to place step progress bar inside td but its static.I am not getting how to bind this step progress bar dynamically.Accepted and rejected are the values that are been fetched.
Here is how it looks:[image] The last td that consist of step progress bar is exactly that I want to bind dynamically.Please feel free to ask if anything else is required?
Code html:

```
<td  style="border-right:1px solid aquamarine;"[class.dot]="user.Manager.status === 'Accepted'"
[class.bluedot]="user.Manager.status === 'rejected'">
  {{user.Manager.status}}
</td>
```

CSS:

```
 .dot{
 overflow: hidden;
 margin-top:10px;
 position: relative;

width: 10px ;
height: 10px ;
border-radius:50%;
background: #66ac3c;
color: white;
text-align: center;
```

}

css of step Progress bar:

```
.line {
width: 100%;
float: float;
margin-top:5px;
border-bottom: 1px solid aquamarine;
```

}

```
.steps {
box-shadow: 0 0 3px #888;
width: 10px;
height: 10px;
border-radius:50%;
background: #66ac3c;
color: black;
text-align: center;
z-index: 10;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will also work as.

`<td style="border-right : 1px solid aquamarine;" 
     [class]="user.Manager.status === 'Accepted'?'dot':'bluedot' " >
  {{user.Manager.status}}
</td>`

Comment: In the screenshot can you tell me why is the 'dot ' not using the height and width that I have provided.It is taking the height and width of entire td by default.

Comment: use element styles like this and it will work

` td.dot{
 overflow: hidden;
 margin-top:10px;
 position: relative;

width: 10px ;
height: 10px ;
border-radius:50%;
background: #66ac3c;
color: white;
text-align: center;
} `

Answer (score 0):

I think that must be work -if user.Manager.status is Accepted and rejected (see the uper and lower letters). Any way you can use ngClass

```
<td  style="border-right:1px solid aquamarine;" 
     [ngClass]="{'dot':user.Manager.status === 'Accepted',
                 'bluedot':user.Manager.status === 'rejected'}">
  {{user.Manager.status}}
</td>
```

Comment: Yes I have even tried this , but I am not able to achieve the step progress bar inside td , is there any other way  in which I could get the similar output ?The step progress bar is just for tracking purpose.